# Define Android Gradle Plugin Version when Building with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

When building my Android project with Cordova, I get the following message when opening in Android Studio:

[image]

My build.gradle file reflects the plugin discrepancy (although the Gradle version defined is correct):

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to configure Cordova to explicitly define an Android Gradle Plugin version.

Comment: I can't make out what exactly you're asking, but this means your grade version is `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0`. The dialog is only asking to update it if you want but if you don't, just click ignore or close it.

Comment: @JoeyDalu It is asking me because cordova specified version 3.0.0 when it built the android platform. I want it to specify 3.2.1 so I don't get this warning.

Comment: Alright, click on the update button and it should update it for you. If it doesn't work, you can always update it in the `settings.gradle` file at the root of your project

Comment: @JoeyDalu I want to configure Cordova to explicitly define an Android Gradle Plugin version as stated in the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Android Gradle plugin version is [hard-coded into the `build.gradle` template](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/bin/templates/project/build.gradle#L31) in [cordova-android](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android).

If you install the platform off the master branch, you can see it's using a higher version (`3.2.0`) than the most recent npm release `cordova-android@7.1.4` which is [configured for `3.0.1`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/rel/7.1.4/bin/templates/project/build.gradle#L32).

To install directly from the master branch:

```
cordova platform add https://github.com/apache/cordova-android
```

If you want to use the very latest version, you could fork the `cordova-android` repo, pin the version you want in the `build.gradle` template, then install the plugin directly from your forked repo:

```
cordova platform add https://github.com/my_github_username/cordova-android
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out and give you credit when I get a chance to try it out.

Comment: Works, but just a note, even though I have verified through Project Structure that my Gradl and plugin Version are correct, it will still flash that update message the first time I open the newly created platform project.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem which required an alternate version of the gradle plugin to be specified in the `platforms/android/build.gradle` file than what the default Cordova android build generated.  So, to fix it, I used created a Cordova hook script to run on `after_platform_add` which modifies the gradle plugin version.

#### Details

The Cordova 9 build was generating a `build.gradle` file with the following gradle plugin version 3.3.0 dependency:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    }
}
```

But, I needed version `3.3.3` of the plugin.

1. In the Cordova `config.xml` file I added this hook in my android platform section:

```
    <platform name="android">
        <hook type="after_platform_add" src="hooks/android/modify-android-gradle-plugin-version.js" />
        ...
    </platform>
```

2. Then I added this `modify-android-gradle-plugin-version.js` hook script. (Please excuse my javascript imperfection, I am not a js expert.)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const deferral = require('q').defer();
const async = require('async');

module.exports = function(ctx) {
    console.log('Running modify-android-gradle-plugin-version.js...');

    const platformRoot = path.join(ctx.opts.projectRoot, 'platforms/android');
    const gradleFiles = [path.join(platformRoot, 'build.gradle')];
    async.each(gradleFiles, function(f, cb) {
        fs.readFile(f, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                cb(err);
                return;
            }
            // regex to replace version 3.3.0 with version 3.3.3
            const result = data.replace(/com\.android\.tools\.build:gradle:3\.3\.0/g, 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.3');
            fs.writeFile(f, result, 'utf8', cb);
        });
    }, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            deferral.reject();
        } else {
            deferral.resolve();
        }

    });
    return deferral.promise;
}
```

3. I also had to add the `async` node module to the `devDependencies` section of my cordova project's `package.json`:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "async": "3.2.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The AGP version or AndroidGooglePlugin can be specified in config.xml through AndroidGradlePluginVersion preference. i.e:

```
<preference name="AndroidGradlePluginVersion" value="7.2.2" />
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!